# JCache with Redisson, how serialization / deserialization works?

Tags: java, redisson, jcache

I am using `JCache` with `Redisson`, it's not clear to me how serialization/deserialization works while using the cache.

When I setup the `Cache` via configuration I didn't setup anything about this. Is this done transparently?

The objects I am storing in cache are lists, objects from `java.time` for example, but I require all of objects of the classes I am storing in the cache implement `Serializable`, is this enough?

Looking at the data on redis it seems it is storing data serialized via java default serialization, am I wrong?

Can I control this behaviour? or it's better to leave it as it is ?

Thanks for help

Comment: from [redisson doc](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/4.-data-serialization) it seems that `Redisson` uses [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) as default data serializer/deserializer. I suppose this is the same when used with `JCache`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment, from [redisson documentation](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/4.-data-serialization) `Redisson` use [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) as default data serializer/deserializer.